# iOS local notification userInfo always null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to schedule a local notification with some custom data attached which I will then read when the user opens the app by clicking on the notification.

I schedule the local notification like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
notification.alertBody = @"Hello World!";
notification.userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"123123123123", @"beaconUUID",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"beaconMajor",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], @"beaconMinor",
                         nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Then in the code which handles the notification I do this:

```
- (void)onAppDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Object = %@", [notification object]);

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSLog(@"UserInfo = %@", userInfo);

    NSString* beaconUUID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"beaconUUID"];
    NSLog(@"Beacon UUID = %@", beaconUUID);
}
```

My problem is that when I try to read the userInfo it always returns null. How do I read the userInfo dictionary from a NSNotification object?

The three NSLog calls from the above code sample print the following in the console:

```
2015-02-04 14:11:52.690 BeaconPlugin[17050:724150] Object = <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7ff1d37199a0>{
fire date = Wednesday, February 4, 2015 at 2:11:51 PM Central European Standard Time, 
time zone = (null), 
repeat interval = 0, 
repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, 
next fire date = (null), 
user info = {
    beaconMajor = 10;
    beaconMinor = 20;
    beaconUUID = 123123123123;
}}
2015-02-04 14:11:52.691 BeaconPlugin[17050:724150] UserInfo = (null)
2015-02-04 14:11:52.691 BeaconPlugin[17050:724150] Beacon UUID = (null)
```

Which does show that the dictionary values are part of the user info. Anybody got any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that method? I think it should be: `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`. Anyway, your app should call `application:DidReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` and you'll be able to access it as you do from that method.

Comment: I am developing a plugin for Phonegap and this is my function which is called from appDelegate.m. This way I can create a plugin without editing the app delegate file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You scheduled a `UILocalNotification` but you are retrieving your user info from a `NSNotification`, this two is not the same.

you should do this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [notification object];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [localNotif userInfo];
NSString* beaconUUID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"beaconUUID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Its worked for when i receive from **didReceiveLocalNotification** protocol

in **AppDelegate.m** file

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    NSLog(@"Object = %@", notification);

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSLog(@"UserInfo = %@", userInfo);

    NSString* beaconUUID = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"beaconUUID"];
    NSLog(@"Beacon UUID = %@", beaconUUID);

}
```

see below output console

```
2015-02-04 19:11:12.937 SampleNO[6676:907] Object = <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x769e780>{fire date = Wednesday, February 4, 2015, 7:11:09 PM India Standard Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = (null), user info = {
        beaconMajor = 10;
        beaconMinor = 20;
        beaconUUID = 123123123123;
    }}
    2015-02-04 19:11:14.621 SampleNO[6676:907] UserInfo = {
        beaconMajor = 10;
        beaconMinor = 20;
        beaconUUID = 123123123123;
    }
    2015-02-04 19:11:18.086 SampleNO[6676:907] Beacon UUID = 123123123123
```